# BetterListView... unable to put an icon and filename on the same row

Tags: listview, icons, filenames

I'm coding in vb.net on windows 10 (not sure if the OS is important or not). I would like to ask a question about BetterListView Express.

On my list I'm putting an Icon then the filename. Problem is, the filename is way to far to the right. Does anyone know how to get the filename just to the right of the icon?

Here's a snippet:

```
exeIcon = Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exePath)

imgList.ImageSize = New Size(16, 16)

With imgList.Images
    .Add(exePath, exeIcon)
    .Add(imgList.Images(0))
End With

With blist.Items
    .Add(imgList.Images(0))
    .Add(p.ProcessName)
End With
```

I can tell from the code that the process name is going to be on separate line. I just don't know how to put them on the same line. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You're also new to stack overflow so I'll have some pity on you. Try reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes I am new to stack overflow. I read the link in your post and see where I'm going wrong. My title was not phrased good for people to have any interest. I'm going to see if I can edit the title. Thanks for point our how to ask a question.

Comment: Is the title better now? I can still change it depending on what you think...

Comment: Thanks for trying! The title should be short, easy to read, and summarize the problem. Something like this `BetterListVeiw Item Text Alignment not Working as Expected`

Comment: Then the question should show the snippet of code that you are using to add the items to the list.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it IS too wordy. I'll try again...

Comment: Much better! It is easier to understand.

Comment: Have you downloaded the sample projects and read the docs from here? http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express

Comment: @StillLearnin I have downloaded the sample projects, but they were compiled in an much older version of VS. It won't load on mine. Guest I could try to open the .vb files in notepad++

Comment: I updated my answer. BTW I'm using VS2015 and the samples compile and run just fine although the design window doesn't load properly. However, the code that you need to see is easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded their sample from [here](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) and opened the vb project.

In this file you should be able to find all the samples you need.

[image]

**Here is the relevant snippet:**

```
    Dim itemCentered = New BetterListViewItem() With {
        .Group = listView.Groups(0), _
        .Text = "Centered" _
    }

    itemCentered.SubItems.Add(New BetterListViewSubItem() With {
                              .AlignHorizontalImage = BetterListViewImageAlignmentHorizontal.OverlayCenter, _
                              .Image = imageItem _
                              })

    listView.Items.AddRange(New BetterListViewItem() {
    itemCentered,
    New BetterListViewItem("Image before text") With { _
        .Group = listView.Groups(0), _
        .Image = imageItem _
    }, New BetterListViewItem("Image after text") With { _
        .AlignHorizontalImage = BetterListViewImageAlignmentHorizontal.AfterTextCenter, _
        .AlignVerticalImage = BetterListViewImageAlignmentVertical.Middle, _
        .Group = listView.Groups(0), _
        .Image = imageItem _
    }, New BetterListViewItem("Top left") With { _
        .AlignHorizontal = TextAlignmentHorizontal.Left, _
        .AlignVertical = TextAlignmentVertical.Top, _
        .Group = listView.Groups(1), _
        .Image = imageItem _
    }, New BetterListViewItem("Middle center") With { _
        .AlignHorizontal = TextAlignmentHorizontal.Center, _
        .AlignVertical = TextAlignmentVertical.Middle, _
        .Group = listView.Groups(1), _
        .Image = imageItem _
    }, New BetterListViewItem("Bottom Right") With { _
        .AlignHorizontal = TextAlignmentHorizontal.Right, _
        .AlignVertical = TextAlignmentVertical.Bottom, _
        .Group = listView.Groups(1), _
        .Image = imageItem _
    }})
```

***Especially Notice*** how the `Image` property is being set.

```
New BetterListViewItem("Top left") With { _
    .AlignHorizontal = TextAlignmentHorizontal.Left, _
    .AlignVertical = TextAlignmentVertical.Top, _
    .Group = listView.Groups(1), _
    .Image = imageItem _
}
```

Comment: I tried every I could think of to code work, but had nothing but failure. Below is my code along with the error messages. I tried with and without setting the property to true. The all were red underlined.
            'blist is the accessible  name
            blistListViewColumnHeader1.AlignHorizontal = True
            'error: Severity Code Description Project File Line
I tried every other alignment properties but none worked. I had all the code for every alignment statement, but this textbox said I had too many characters. Thanks for the help, Am I doing it wrong or what?

Comment: HI again. I'm sorry but I did not see your answer. Guess I was too busy trying to get my comment right. I tried the code, but the behavior did not change anything. .addrange worked the same way that .add did. THANK YOU so much for trying to help. I really appreciate it my friend.

Comment: Think I'm about to give up on the BetterListView control. Maybe I might have better luck with the Metro TreeView... Quick edit: Metro doesn't have a TreeView ha ha

Comment: I wish I could put a screen shot in here so you would know what I'm talking about. Oh yeah, sticking with BetterListView :)